# Ionic2: No provider Error

Tags: ionic2

I am using `Ionic2 rc4`.

> ```
> Your system information:
>
> Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
> Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
> Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
> Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
> Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
> ios-deploy version: Not installed
> ios-sim version: Not installed
> OS: macOS Sierra
> Node Version: v6.9.4
> Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
> ```

I would like to add a service.  I have other `Services`, that work perfectly. So I configure this new Service (`PayPalService`) the same.

**payPalTest.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { PayPalService } from '../paypal/PayPalService';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'payPalTest.html'
})
export class PayPalTestPage {
  public payPalService: PayPalService = null;

  constructor( @Inject(forwardRef(() => PayPalService)) payPalService) {
    this.payPalService = payPalService;
  }

  public payOut(): void {
    alert('payOut');
    //this.payPalService.payOut();
  }

}
```

**payPalService.ts**

```
declare var require: any;
var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
//import {paypal-rest-sdk} from './paypal-rest-sdk';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class PayPalService {

    public paypal: any = null;

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { PayPalService } from "../pages/paypal/payPalService";
import { PayPalTestPage } from "../pages/paypal/payPalTest";
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      ...
    PayPalTestPage
      ...
  entryComponents: [
      ...
    PayPalTestPage
      ...
  ...
  providers: [..., PayPalService]
```

However, I get the following error.

**Error**

> Runtime Error Error in ./MyApp class MyApp - caused by: No provider
>   for PayPalService!

I think the error is related to the way I import the [`'paypal-rest-sdk'`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK).

```
declare var require: any;
var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
```

I installed the [paypal-rest-sdk](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK) as follows:

```
npm install paypal-rest-sdk
```

And the new package has been added to the `node_modules`.

**Question**

Can anyone please suggest how I can resolve the above error please?

**UPDATE**

If I remove all reference to the PayPal api by commenting out the following two lines:

**payPalService.ts**

```
// declare var require: any;
// var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
```

I get the following error:

**Error**

> Runtime Error Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or
>   directory, open
>   '/Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo/src/pages/paypal/payPalService.js'
>   at Error (native)

Comment: don't you know where the Ionic team has released version 2.2.x also now? why you're still using buggy versions?

Comment: that SDK mentions nodejs.. is it server side? or do you mean to use http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/paypal/ ?

Comment: Hi Suraj, the reason I am not using the ionic-native version of PayPal is because it does not do PayOuts (make payments to other PayPal accounts).

Comment: Hi Sampath, I am using the version see above (updated). I haven't updated yet because I have been busy developing tbh and was not aware of the upgrades.  Do you think the upgrade will fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It was a really silly mistake by me. The import had the incorrect case.

Change:

**payPalTest.ts**

```
import { PayPalService } from '../paypal/PayPalService';
```

to:

```
import { PayPalService } from '../paypal/payPalService';
```